# byte to int with twos complement

Tags: c, go

The following [snippet of C code](http://git.osmocom.org/rtl-sdr/tree/src/rtl_fm.c#n798) is from `rtl_fm.c` which is part of the [rtlsdr](http://sdr.osmocom.org/trac/wiki/rtl-sdr) project (I've added the `printf` statement)

```
for (i=0; i<(int)len; i++) {
    s->buf16[i] = (int16_t)buf[i] - 127; 
}    
printf("buf %x %x, buf16 %x %x\n", buf[0],buf[1], s->buf16[0], s->buf16[1]);
```

An example line of output is: `buf 7c 82, buf16 fffd 3`

`buf16` is an array of type *int16_t*, `buf` is an array of bytes (char*), `len` is length of `buf`

I'd like to port this to Go. Here is what I've come up with: http://play.golang.org/p/zTRkjlz8Ll however it doesn't produce the correct output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For example,

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

func main() {

    buf := []byte{0x7c, 0x82}
    buf16 := make([]int16, len(buf))
    for i := range buf {
        buf16[i] = int16(buf[i]) - 127
    }
    fmt.Printf(
        "buf %x %x, buf16 %x %x\n",
        buf[0], buf[1], uint16(buf16[0]), uint16(buf16[1]),
    )
}
```

Output:

```
buf 7c 82, buf16 fffd 3
```